# Android build with ProGuard runs indefinitely with AGP 3.2.0 or later

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

After updating to Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0 or 3.3.0-alpha13, my builds that have ProGuard enabled continue to run indefinitely.
If I roll back to AGP 3.1.4 or earlier, build succeeds as it should.
If I disable optimizations with `-dontoptimize` flag, build succeeds as well.

Build type is configured like this:

```
release {
  minifyEnabled true
  useProguard true
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

proguard-rules.pro:

```
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable,!method/removal/parameter
-repackageclasses ''

-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-keepattributes Exceptions

# Crashlytics
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable
-keepclassmembers public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***11/11/2018: Updated to include the real cause and fix***

This problem was bugging me until I accidentally stumbled upon [this issue](https://github.com/square/okio/issues/516) on Okio GitHub page.

Turns out that in my case this issue was caused by combination of things:
`Okio 2.1.0` + `AGP >= 3.2.0` + `ProGuard (<6.1.0-beta1) with optimizations` = `Infinite execution of optimization step (build never finishes)`

If you were to take out any part from this equation, everything would work fine.

Possible **solutions** in detail:

1. Use Okio 2.0.0 or 1.x.x.
2. Stick to AGP 3.1.4 or earlier.
3. Disable optimizations with `-dontoptimize` flag in your ProGuard config.
4. Use R8 instead of ProGuard:

   - For AGP 3.2.x: add `android.enableR8=true` to your gradle.properties.
   - For AGP
     3.3.x: R8 is enabled by default. **Note:** You can use any AGP >= 3.3.0-alpha01, but the latest (at the moment it's 3.3.0-beta03) is recommended.

Each solution has its drawbacks, but the most production-friendly are probably (**1**) using earlier Okio versions if you don't need v.2.1.0 specifically, or (**3**) disabling optimizations if you can afford to have somewhat bigger APK.

**UPDATE:**
The issue is confirmed to happen because of ProGuard and is fixed in its latest beta release. It's not clear when this version would be incorporated in AGP by default, but you can use it right now at your own peril (seeing as it's still in beta):

```
buildscript {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.1.0beta1'
        }
    }
}
```